# C++ Are there disadvantages in turning attributes into pointers to reduce size of class?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am using a `std::vector<T>` (16 bytes) in my class. This increases the size of my class by 16 bytes. Beeing a heavy used class (also in arrays), I considered replacing `std::vector<T>` with `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>` to go down to 4 bytes of size. So are there any disadvantages in doing so? Or is this just a usual step in designing memory friendly classes?

Edit: I was considering this method in the first place, because I assumed instances of my class where I don't construct any of my pointers. But appearently `std::optional` is a better choice here, as SergeyA thankfully pointed out.

Edit 2: Since the answer is *Yes, there are disadvantages* and `std::optional` isn't exactly what I was looking for either, I feel like I have to clarify further (and explain more of my implementation). I will re-write my question in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885516/c-alternating-between-two-variables-at-compile-time). This turns out to be a lot more complicated than I initially expected.

Comment: You added an additional level of indirection and possibly increased cache miss rate.

Comment: But do not delete this one.

Comment: No, I will keep it.

Comment: Why are you trying to reduce the size of your class? Does it have to fit somewhere? Or have you actually measured that copying it slows you down? Plus, does your vector have a constant size?

Comment: In boost library you will probably find a "vector" the best suits your needs. Maybe [small_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/container/small_vector.html)

Answer (score 4):

By doing so, you would **increase** the memory consumption of the application - now every object will use 8 bytes for the `unique_ptr` in addition to 16 bytes for the vector, allocated somewhere else in the dynamic storage (heap).

You also would increase memory fragmentation and add an extra indirection step when accessing the said vector - resulting in performance degradation.

However, if you have optionality, that is, some objects would have vector, but some would not, it would be better to express this with a specifically designed tool: `std::optional` (part of C++17 or `experimental` in pre-C++17 compilers).

Comment: I think OP might be compiling for 32-bit addresses. Bear in mind that `std::vector` cannot be less than 24 bytes if, for 64-bit addresses, it needs to maintain a Stateful allocator.

Comment: But if I where to not construct the `unique_ptr` (in a `make_unique<T>()` way) it wouldn't allocate any more memory in the heap, right?

Comment: @Xirema, forgot the allocator. Thanks for reminding, I will remove this section.

Comment: @ParadobC2 if  you mean to convey the fact that some of the objects would not have a vector there at all, `std::optional` is a better choice. I will add this to answer.

Comment: Oh `std::optional` sounds exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: If `std::vector` is a member, what is the point of making it `std::optional`? `sizeof(std::optional<std::vector<T>>)` will **always** be **larger** than `sizeof(std::vector<T>)`. This is not what OP wants.

Comment: An empty vector does not use any memory heap so optional vector is a really bad choice. Whatsoever empty vector already means there are no elements.

Comment: I never said that it would be a move to save memory. I said, it would be a move to convey optionality for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

As the [answer by SergeyA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51883073/434551) clearly points out, you will not gain anything by using `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>`.

However, if there is a possibility to share the contents of `std::vector<T>`s across many instances of your class, you would potentially improve the overall memory footprint of your program by using `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save memory, `std::optional` is definitely not a better choice. Loosely speaking, `std::optional<T>` is just a collection of `T` and a `bool` flag. Hence, its size is always larger than the size of `T` (to hold that additional `bool` value), regardless of whether `std::optional` contains a value or not. Typically, `sizeof(std::optional<std::vector<T>>) = sizeof(std::vector<T>) + 4`.

Quoting [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

> If an `optional<T>` contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. no dynamic memory allocation ever takes place. Thus, an optional object models an object, not a pointer, even though `operator*()` and `operator->()` are defined.

**Addition.** If `T` is simple enough (e.g., POD) and you don't need all the facilities of `std::vector<T>`, consider using `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage of wrapping a vector in a unique_ptr. This is because the inline storage of a vector is small while the main storage buffer of the vector is already a pointer and therefore easily movable (just copy the pointer). Adding a unique_ptr just adds another level of indirection slowing access down with a large potential for a cache miss thrown in for good measure.

Now were the vector a std::array or a large struct, things would be different. Adding a unique_ptr makes the array or struct movable without having to do a full copyb and also may push memory use from the stack to the heap saving valuable stack space.