# C++ Alternating between two variables at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, c++17

Suppose you have a class that operates on a vector:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo() {
        m_dynamic_data.push_back(5);
        std::cout << m_dynamic_data[0] << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> m_dynamic_data;
};
```

In my case this class is huge with 2500 additional lines of code.
This class behaves dynamic (hence `std::vector`). But I would also like to provide a "static" implementation (using `std::array`). So `std::size_t N` is added, which now should control when to use which attribute.

```
template<std::size_t N>
class Foo{
private:
    std::vector<int> m_dynamic_data;  //use this, when N == 0
    std::array<int, N> m_static_data; //use this, when N != 0
};
```

I am not sure if I can get this to work. using `#define` won't do the job (since it can't alternate). `constexpr` can't be wrapped around two attributes either. The best solution is probably to provide a base class and then inherit the dynamic and static case from it. But before I spent the next days doing this, I wonder if there isn't a technique afterall.

I thought about putting both into a `std::unique_ptr` and only constructing the relevant array:

```
template<std::size_t N>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        if constexpr (N) {
            m_static_data_ptr = std::make_unique<std::array<int, N>>();
            (*m_static_data_ptr)[0] = 5;
            std::cout << (*m_static_data_ptr)[0] << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            m_dynamic_data_ptr = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(1);
            (*m_dynamic_data_ptr)[0] = 5;
            std::cout << (*m_dynamic_data_ptr)[0] << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> m_dynamic_data_ptr;
    std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, N>> m_static_data_ptr;
};
```

I earlier asked about this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883017/c-are-there-disadvantages-in-turning-attributes-into-pointers-to-reduce-size-o?noredirect=1#comment90719185_51883017). But apparently this doesn't seem like a good approach. (fragmenting memory, cache miss rate). `std::optional` also seems interesting, but it pushes the sizeof(Foo) too far for my goal.

Ultimately there is also using `void` pointers:

```
template<std::size_t N>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        if constexpr (N) {
            m_data = malloc(sizeof(std::array<int, N>));
            (*static_cast<std::array<int, N>*>(m_data))[0] = 5;
            std::cout << (*static_cast<std::array<int, N>*>(m_data))[0] << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            m_data = new std::vector<int>;
            (*static_cast<std::vector<int>*>(m_data)).push_back(5);
            std::cout << (*static_cast<std::vector<int>*>(m_data))[0] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~Foo() {
        delete[] m_data;
    }
private:
    void* m_data;
};
```

But this seems pretty dirty [...]
So the goal would be to work with either array structure at compile time. Thanks for any help / suggestion!

Comment: Template your class on both size and type of container?

Comment: You could use a `union` and just use `if (N) ...` to brach on using the vector or array.

Comment: But I can't use `resize(...)` on `std::array`

Comment: Then put the code that does a `resize` in an `if constexpr` branch (not entirely sure if that works, but you can do something like that)

Comment: What do you mean by "alternate"? That word means that you'd switch every time you compile, like 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0... I think you probably want to be able to switch back and for depending on which one you need for given circumstances. Your subject says "at compile time," which makes it hard to understand why `#define` won't do the trick. If you want to be able to choose at run time, then set a flag when you create the object.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `push_back doesn't affect m_data`?

Comment: @Justin but `std::array` has the size paramter, I can't seem to get this working while also templating for `std::vector`

Comment: @Axalo when running the code (creating a `Foo<0>` instance) it crashes *_Pnext was 0xCDCDCDD1.* I printed out `->size()` and it was `0` after `push_back`

Comment: @Caleb `#define` appears to "gate" only once. I tried it, it permanently exluded the other attribute.

Comment: @ParadobC2 That's probably because `malloc` doesn't actually create a `std::vector` object. You either need to use `new std::vector<...>` or [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: @ParadobC2 Yes, using a #define would choose which storage scheme to use once, *at compile time*, which is what you say you want. If you want to be able to switch between the two schemes, you need to be able to select which one to use while the program is running, which means either creating two different classes or setting a flag when you instantiate, or something like that. But as written, we can't really tell what you want or what your problem is.

Comment: @Caleb but this forbids me from creating a Foo<0> and a Foo<5> in the same environment! But I need both

Comment: @Axalo interesting, why does it work for `std::array` then?

Comment: Because `std::array<int>` is a POD, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674247/is-stdarrayt-s-guaranteed-to-be-pod-if-t-is-pod), but don't rely on that, always construct your objects properly otherwise you get UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R Sahu's answer is great, but you don't need to access the container indirectly through a struct.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct FooData { using type = std::array<int, N>;};

template <>
struct FooData<0> { using type = std::vector<int>; };

template<std::size_t N>
using FooData_t = typename FooData<N>::type;

template<std::size_t N>
class Foo{
   private:
      FooData_t<N> data;
};
```

Alternatively, you can also use `std::conditional_t`:

```
template<std::size_t N>
class Foo{
   private:
      std::conditional_t<N==0, std::vector<int>, std::array<int, N>> data;
};
```

Comment: I like this even more, because I don't have to add `.container` after each call to the variable. Thanks! Perfect

Answer (score 4):

You can abstract the *data* part of `Foo` to another class template.

```
template<std::size_t N> struct FooData
{
   std::array<int, N> container;
}

template <> struct FooData<0>
{
   std::vector<int> container;
}

template<std::size_t N>
class Foo{
   private:
      using DataType = FooData<N>;
      DataType data;
};
```

You have to add member functions to `FooData` to support additional abstractions. The number of such functions and their interface depends on how differently you use the containers in `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to isolate this dynamic/static "morphing" from the rest of your giant 2500-lines `Foo` class. I can imagine a tiny wrapper around `std::array` to mimic the interface of `std::vector`. It can be used as a member of `Foo`. If the static capacity is set to the sentinel value `0`, then it can be specialized to just derive from a real `std::vector`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class value_type_, std::size_t capacity_>
struct StaticOrDynamic {
  using value_type = value_type_;
  static constexpr std::size_t capacity = capacity_;

  std::array<value_type, capacity> arr_{};
  std::size_t size_{0};

  constexpr void push_back(const value_type& x) {
    assert(size_ < capacity && "must not exceed capacity");
    arr_[size_++] = x;
  }

  constexpr const value_type_& at(std::size_t i) const {
    assert(i < size_ && "must be in [0, size)");
    return arr_[i];
  }

/* other members etc */
};

template<class value_type_>
struct StaticOrDynamic<value_type_, 0>// specialization for dynamic case
  : std::vector<value_type_>
{
  using std::vector<value_type_>::vector;
};

template<std::size_t capacity_>
struct Foo {
  static constexpr std::size_t capacity = capacity_;

  StaticOrDynamic<int, capacity> m_data_{};

  Foo() {// static version may be constexpr (without debug output)
    m_data_.push_back(5);
    std::cout << m_data_.at(0) << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo<5> static_foo{};
  Foo<0> dynamic_foo{};
}
```

A similar behavior (static/dynamic chosen by a template parameter) [is offered in, e.g., the Eigen library](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html). I do not know how it is implemented there.